# Mixing Twig and Angular? For a Frontend query service for searching a table

Tags: angularjs, search, twig, frontend

What I want to do is go get a frontend query service for searching a table. Like this http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-3/app/
I already implemented that with Angular. My question is, if there's a similar way to do that with Twig, or any other possibilities? Is it even recommend to mix Angular with Twig?

Btw, I'm new to this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Two Different Approaches**

The filter in your example completely takes place in the frontend. It loads all the data on siteload and filters them afterwards. If you wanted to achieve a similar result with mostly server side code you would probably use more like a search feature than just a filter. What you do is setting a delay on keypress and then send an ajax request to the server which does the query and renders the result. This especially makes sense if your dataset is huge and you can not load all of your content on siteload before filtering it.

**When Using Twig and Angular Together**

However, If you use twig and angular together you should either define an alias on frontend for angular or enclose curly braces for angular in quotes on server side.

**Define Alias For Angular Variables**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
});
```

**Use Quotes On Server Side**

```
{{ '{{' ~ yourvariable ~ '}}' }}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I guess that the ajax request is the best variant for me, cause the dataset will be huge.